# How do I ensure that RTMP Streams from different Android devices have the same SPS/PPS?

Tags: android, rtmp

The three Android devices that I am testing out have three different AVC packets. Here below are the samples for Samsung, Motorola, and Doffe.

Samsung
1700000000014d001effe10012674d001eda0280bfe5948283030368509a8001000468ee0

Motorola
1700000000014d001effe10012674d001ee901405ff2ca41418181b4284d4001000468ee06e2

Doofe
170000000001640029ffe1001067640029ac1b1a80a02ff9601e1108a701000468ea43cb

This causes huge problems when I interleave the videos. The Video player gets obviously confused and does not play.

How do I ensure that the video headers are the same? Should I use a software encoder and bypass the hardware encoders?

Answer (score 0):

How is carried out encoding on the clients?

PPS  SPS describe your video stream parameters like frame sizes, profile, etc. and almost always are generated by encoder.

> How do I ensure that the video headers are the same?

Therefore, you have to ensure all devices use the same video encoder and publish video with the same format (frame size, bitrate, fps, profile, key frame count, etc)

> Should I use a software encoder and bypass the hardware encoders?

In your case, preferentially to use soft encoders. But you first just can try to make encoders configurations the same. Most likely it resolve your issue

Comment: Thanks, Onix. We did implement Software encoders and works like a charm. You are right on!